# Angular directive with custom / conditional actions

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have questions about Angular directives.  The following is my code:

main controller & the directive:

```
<div ng-controller='ShopsController'>
    <update-createform shop="shop" action='update()'></update-createform>
</div>
```

directive js: 
(this way the direction action will take the 'action' input argument)

```
angular.module('app')
.directive('updateCreateform', function(){
  return {
    templateUrl: '/form.html', 
    restrict : 'E', 
    scope: {
        shop: '=', 
        action: '&'
    }
  }
})
```

form.html template:

```
<form name="shopForm" ng-submit='action(shopForm.$valid)' novalidate>
<input type='text' name='name' required/>
<input type='text' name='description' required/>
</form>
```

ShopsController has a method:

```
exports.update = function(isValid) {
    if (isValid) { /* update the shop*/ }
}
```

What I am doing is I am passing the shop data I get from the server, send it into the form so I can view and/or update the shop info.

It's also that I want to create shop info using the same form. In this case I just send in shop = [] and action='create()' instead.

My controller has an update method that takes the argument isValid. I don't know how to pass the directive shopForm.$valid outside and send it to server.

Two questions:

1. how do I get **isValid** variable from the directive?
2. Following Ari Lerner's ng-book:  He said it's possible to do the following:

http://www.scribd.com/doc/215682987/NG-Book-The-Complete-Book-on-AngularJS-2013

instead of using directive above we use

```
<update-createform shop="shop" on-update='update()' on-create='create()'></update-createform>
```

and the directive 'action' will change to 'update' when shop is not empty otherwise action equals to 'create'?   I tried his code but I cannot get it to work..

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: should it be `<update-createform shop="shop" action='exports.update()'></update-createform>`? Have you tried putting a link function of the directive and using console.log to see what 'action' is being passed in as?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add an argument to `action=update(isValid)`. This then gets resolved on the form submit.

So your html would look like this

```
<div ng-controller='ShopsController as shopCtrl'>
  <update-createform shop="shop" action='shopCtrl.update(isValid)'></update-createform>
</div>
```

And your form would look like like this

```
<form name="shopForm" ng-submit='action({isValid:shopForm.$valid})' novalidate>
    <input type='text' name='name' required/>
    <input type='text' name='description' required/>
    <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

and controller would be

```
.controller('ShopsController', function() {

  var exports = this;

  exports.update = function(isValid) {
    console.log(isValid)
    if (isValid) { /* update the shop*/ }
  }
})
```

http://plnkr.co/edit/Qh3HzKGnOo1NTP9Pfsmh?p=preview

**OR**

There's another way, although personally i find the syntax a little odd. Not that the first solution feels that intuitive either.

http://plnkr.co/edit/CRN9ruRekJiozJIBTe80?p=preview

Found that one in an excellent post about directives by Dan Wahlin

http://weblogs.asp.net/dwahlin/creating-custom-angularjs-directives-part-3-isolate-scope-and-function-parameters

Comment: this code is somehow not working for me.  I put a alert('valid') statement in the controller and try to submit the code. It displays 'valid' even when the form is empty. Maybe I missed something??

Comment: Did you look at the plunker?

Comment: yes I did. if you change the .js line to if (isValid) { alert(123) } the alert will only be triggered when your form passes validation right?  But somehow I get alert(123) even when the form is empty..

Comment: The behaviour's correct. You don't have ng-model on your inputs, so there's nothing to validate. http://plnkr.co/edit/ziEX3FsXB0fM43r083Db?p=preview

Comment: one more questions.  In the code you put shopCtrl.update(isValid). This works. But if I just put update(isValid) isn't it that it will find it in its parent scope anyway?  (In this case ShopsController?)

Comment: You'll notice in my example i'm using the `controllerAs` syntax (ShopsController as shopCtrl), so the `update` function's not being attached directly to `$scope`. If you inspect $scope you'll see that instead it has a property called `shopCtrl` which in turn has an `update` function. Which is why you're unable to access it directly in the way you suggest. You could achieve what you're suggesting by just adding the `update` function directly to $scope (in the ShopsController), but this is considered bad practice, as you're polluting the `$scope`object.

Comment: If you're going to add properties/functions to `$scope` you should always 'hang' them off another object. i.e `$scope.viewModel = {}; $scope.viewModel.update = function(){...}`, to prevent directly polluting the $scope object. Which is essentially what the `controllerAs` syntax does for you.

Comment: Thanks a lot by the way.   It seems working now let me fully test it for another while!

Comment: I get carried away with some backend problems for now.. I'll come back to test this again in a while man!

Comment: thanks so much for your answer.  This works well as I have tested it for a while!

Comment: also I was wondering what is the $parse doing here? The example seems to work even when there's no $parse?

Comment: I've removed it now, it was just left in there by mistake.